# Spring security clarifications

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am new to Spring security and learnt the concepts of `AuthenticationInterceptor`, `AuthenticationManager`, `UserLoginService`. I know how to implement the userloginservice for checking a valid user in the system. The problem is we have two types of users 1)Specialists 2) Users and their credentials are stored in two different tables. The implementation of `UserDetailsService` should check both tables to authenticate and get the details of the user. Is there possibility to use multiple authentication providers and use the appropriate one based upon the type of user? or Do I have to use the same authentication provider to query both tables to find out the user validity? What is the best way to handle this scenarios when the user has to be searched in two tables?

Comment: Do you want to have one factor authentication, such as username, and by having username you want to search this in different tables? For example, X user tried to login and you checked X in user table, and also in another table?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do sth like that:

```
@Autowired
private UsersDAO usersDAO;

@Autowired
private OtherDAO otherDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    Users user = usersDAO.find(username);
    Other oth  = otherDAO.find(username);

    // your queries

    if(check if your desire is correct based on user){
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getUserRole());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    } else {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, we can do it this way. I am looking for any other better possibilities. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You may want to change your authentication manager. Maybe this post can meet your requirements. http://krams915.blogspot.com.tr/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration-using_26.html